# Input Sanitizing to not break JSON syntax

Tags: java, regex, json, replaceall

So, in a nutshell I'm trying to create a regex that I can use in a java program that is about to submit a JSON object to my php server.

`myString.replaceAll(myRegexString,"");`

My question is that I am absolutely no good with regex and to add onto that I need to escape the characters properly as its stored in a string, and then also escape the characters properly inside the regex.   good lordy.

What I came up with was this:

`String myRegexString = "[\"',{}[]:;]"`

The first backslash was to escape outer quotes to get a " in there.  And then it struck me that {} and [] are also regex commands.  Would I escape those as well?  Like:

`String myRegexString = "[\"',\{\}\[\]:;]"`

Thanks in advance.   In case it wasnt clear from examples above the only characters I really care about at this moment in time is:
`" { } [ ] ,` and also `; : '` for general sqlinj protection.

UPDATE:

This is the final regex:
`[\\Q\"',{}[\]:;\\E]` for anyone else curious.  Thanks Amit!

Comment: For those escaped characters, you'll need double-backslashes.  E.g. `"[\\"',\\{\\}\\[\\]\\:;]"` so that Java passes the backslash character to the regex engine.  Otherwise Java looks for the special character `\[` which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Matt, the `"` must not be double escaped (or else a compile time error occurs). Also, the `{`, `)` and `:` need no escapes inside at all inside a character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
String myRegexString = "[\\Q\"',{}[]:;\\E]";
```

now the characters between \Q and \E are now treated as normal characters.

Comment: Hey thanks for the cool notation.  According to regex helper i had to escape the ] as well or it ended the series prematurely.  So I got `[\\Q\"',{}[\]:;\\E]`  In java, will I need to double up on all of those backslashes?

Comment: Nvm.  got my answer with a little test script. I'll re-post the final one up top in case others might need use of it.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use an actual JSON encoding API/framework? What you're doing is not sanitizing. What you're doing is corrupting the data. If my name is O'Reilly, I want it to be spelled O'Reilly, not OReilly. If I send a message containing [ or {, I want these to be in the messages. Use a framework or API that escapes those characters when needed rather than removing them blindly.

Googling for JSON Java will lead you to many APIs and frameworks.

Comment: I agree, I am corrupting the data.  But it's what I need to do.  I don't care if you want your username to be O'Reilly, to stick it in my database, it's going to be OReilly.

Comment: Well its a casual game, and the wonderful part about this is that is you want your username to be O'Reilly you can keep typing O'Reilly.  It'll come thru as OReilly every time and it will still work.

Comment: Making things "work" is not sufficient when you're a serious developer. You have to make things work well and right. Imagine if this web site (stackoverflow.com) did remove all the quotes, brackets and curly braces from all posts. Sure it would still work. But would anyone use it? And if you plan to avoid SQL injection attacks by filtering ; and ', you're doing it plain wrong, and it won't work. Use prepared statements.